# Async method doesnt continue to following code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I wanna create some nested folders the object i m sending if have parent id when i debug it after await it act like break its not following next code line what can i do i couldnt find any solution on internet.

```
public class FileOperations
{
    StorageFolder newFile,newFolder;
    List<StorageFolder> folderList = new List<StorageFolder>();
    public async void CreatingFiles(int cat, int par, string name)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if (par == 0)
        {
            StorageFolder file = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            newFile = await file.CreateFolderAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            folderList.Add(newFile);
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= folderList.Count; i++)
                if (par == i)
                {
                    newFolder =  await folderList[par - 1].CreateFolderAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
folderList.Add(newFolder);
                }
        }
    }
    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        return InitializeOfflineFilesAsync();
    }

    private Task InitializeOfflineFilesAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private async Task<StorageFolder> CF(string name, CreationCollisionOption replaceExisting, StorageFolder file)
    {
        return await file.CreateFolderAsync(name, replaceExisting);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work? Also what does your else part do with the loop? It reminds me of the [For-If-Antipattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx)

Comment: And you should also avoid `async void` methods. They almost exclusively exist for event handlers. `async Task` is the asynchronous equivalent to a `void` synchronous method.

Comment: How are you calling this? Do you have a `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried returning Task type instead of void for "CreatingFiles" method and calling "CreatingFiles" method with await?

e.g. await CreatingFiles(...);

I guess you call async method a few times, you don't want other async method to start before previous async method finishes, but it does. To prevent this situation you must call "CreatingFiles" method with await to wait for it to finish before it continues to implement.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Asynchronous refers to processes that do not depend on each other's outcome, and can therefore occur on different threads simultaneously. So i think the problem is that you run one third and then you switch on different third, you must be in same third if you want to continue. The solution is to use dispecher on line code that break:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    var x = await ...;
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work on dispatcher it says " 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" it doesnt accept using System.Windows.Threading